# ESLint error "'svelte' is not defined" when using svelte.JSX.MouseEventHandler

Tags: typescript, eslint, svelte, svelte-3

In a SvelteKit project, I have included the a svelte type. My problem is that my linting (ESLint) throws an error saying that 'svelte' is not defined. My code is as follows:

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let action: svelte.JSX.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | string;
</script>
```

I can of course change the typing to the more generic void, but is there any way to keep it as is?

Comment: Do you have `globals: { svelte: true }` defined in your eslint configuration? That was what I had missing in there